# Durant / dans / en ces dernières minutes

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Je n’ai pas pensé à lui **durant** ces dernières minutes.

Il est possible de remplacer "durant" par "dans".

> Je n’ai pas pensé à lui **dans** ces dernières minutes.

Mais en même temps, on dit :

> Je te rejoindrai **dans** cinq minutes.

Pourquoi on utilise "dans" pour parler du futur et du passé ?

Est-ce que "en" est aussi possible dans ma phrase ?

> Je n’ai pas pensé à lui **en** ces dernières minutes.

Comment: *Durant* permet de compter le passage de chacune de ces minutes, alors que *dans* indique la durée totale de la période, Quel que soit le lieu, l'époque. — « *En ce temps*-là, que dis-je, *en ces [dernières] minutes* précieuses … tout est possible selon le contexte ! » … enfin, cela n'engage que l'auteur·e épicène du commentaire, pas l'Académie

Comment: "Je n'ai pas pensé à lui durant ou dans ces dernières minutes." me fait penser à un narrateur qui est mort et qui raconte la fin de sa vie, "minutes" étant le plus souvent qualifiéés par des nombres: 4, 10, etc. autrement.

Answer (score 1):

*Pourquoi on utilise "dans" pour parler du futur et du passé ?*

Ce n'est pas exactement le même *dans*.

1. ***Dans** ces dernières minutes* : Il s'agit d'une période de temps (toutes les dernières minutes), *dans* signifie *à l'intérieur* de cette période. Un autre exemple: *Il y a eu trois buts dans les cinq dernières minutes du match*. On peut remplacer *dans* par *pendant* ou *durant*. Que ce soit dans le passé, au présent ou au futur n'a pas d'importance :

   *[Dans les années 70](https://www.emissionreplay.fr/la-fievre-des-annees-disco), le disco, au-delà d'un simple courant musical, est devenu un véritable phénomène de société.*

   *On peut imaginer que [dans les années qui viennent](https://www.francebleu.fr/infos/societe/demographie-dans-l-yonne-forte-baisse-dans-le-sud-le-tiers-nord-a-la-hausse-1577812089) la population continuera de baisser.*
2. ***Dans** cinq minutes* : Il s'agit d'une échéance, la cinquième minute à partir de maintenant. *Dans* signifie : *au moment de cette échéance*.

On sera compris si on dit ***en** ces dernières minutes* mais le ton sera très solennel.